# AFrame specify WebGL version

Tags: three.js, aframe

AFrame 1.1.0 is using THREE.js 123, which by default is now using WebGL2.
Some AFrame components are not working with WebGL2 yet.  It would be great if we could use the AFrame with WebGL1.  THREE.js still supports WebGL1 rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the maintainer of AFrame, this is not possible currently with 1.1.0.

[image: diego-response]

AFrame creates its own canvas in `a-scene.js` `setupCanvas()`, so you can't pass in one with the webgl1 context already set.

We ended up making a patch to our own version of AFrame.  You can see the logic here for specifying whether or not to use WebGL2 vs WebGL1 using the `renderer` system.

https://github.com/8thwall/8frame/commit/533c4304f20153834a85f60a19e161e61ce71ec6

Even with the patch, there are still issues with webgl1 around shader GLSL compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

When creating the renderer, you can [pass your own canvas and context](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer) to the constructor, instead of letting the engine create its own. So you could simply grab the `<canvas>` HTMLElement, [request a WebGL1 context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) from it, and use them when initializing the renderer:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

var renderer = new WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: myCanvas,
    context: gl
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Marquizzo.  However, this works for THREE.js.  How would you get it working for AFrame?